# Status 200 data undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http

Estou montando uma aplicação em angular, onde dou http.get em uma url, o status vem 200, mas a data vem vazia. 
Na api onde montei, eu retorno o array em json, e no webservice no angular, eu apneas dou http.get e a data me retorna vazia.

Segue código do meu service:

```
myApp.service('cinemas',function($http){

    return ({
        getList:getCinemasList
    });

    function getCinemasList(){
        return $http.get("http://api.localhost:8080/movie/204").then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Se você chamar o link no navegador retorna um json certo?

Comment: sim, no navegador retorna.

Comment: Aperta F12, vai na aba network, pega sua Request e verifique no content da response, se o servidor está te enviando o retorno.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta algo assim:

```
.factory('MeuService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
 var URL = "MinhaUrl";
return {
    getCinemas: function(){
     var deffered = $q.defer();
     $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: URL
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            deffered.resolve(response.data);
          });
        return deffered.promise;
    }
}
}])
```

Comment: eu consigo acessar, de todos meus servidores, eu tenho um xampp rodando e consigo acessar, tenho um servidor externo rodando e consigo acessar, mas esse servidor que estou tentando acessar é um laravel, e estou rodando via artisan, eu testei meu service e ele conseguiu pegar os dados de todos servidores, menos do laravel que está rodando via artisan

Comment: Pode ser CORS, dá uma olhada: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs

Comment: Não entendi muito bem pra que serve isso. Eu queria entender o porque de funcionar na minha rede localhost normal, e não funcionar no via artisan do laravel, se é local igual qualquer outro server como xampp,wamp,etc..

Comment: Cors é uma restrição de segurança, e o servidor pode estar bloqueando a requisição, por isso não exibe o resultado esperado. veja se esse link resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792134/allowing-cors-in-artisan-serve

Comment: No log do navegador aparece alguma msg?

Comment: aparece valor nullo